# How can I make my foreign keys case sensitive on a database with a case-insensitive collation?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, foreign-keys, collation

I've got a database with a CI default collation (`French_CI_AS`)

Under this collation, SQL Server will do case insensitive checks on my foreign keys, which makes sense, but is causing me quite a few problems, mostly because string comparison doesn't have the same behavior in my database tier and in my application tier

I've got probably around twenty `varchar` PKs and hundreds of FKs on those `varchar` PKs (yes, I know using only `bigint` as PKs would have avoided the issue in the first place, but moving from `varchar` to `bigint` is not an option here)

What's the easiest way to sort this out? I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: You cannot. If the database collation is case-insensitive, then all comparisons (used by FK->PK links) are case-insensitive.... no "magic" to change that.... and **yes** - using `varchar` as PK is a **really bad idea** - this is just one of the many reasons why you shouldn't use `varchar` as PK .....

Comment: Wouldn't a COLLATE in the column definition help? `CREATE TABLE ... column_name <data_type> COLLATE collation_name`?

Comment: @marc_s : of course I can. For example, I could change the collation of the whole detabase to case sensitive. I'm just trying to find as painless a way as possible to achieve my initial goal...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to change the collation of the column to case sensitive, but then you will need to cast the column (or other columns to  the same colation) when you use it in joins or comparisons.

Comment: Actually, SQL Server will require the foreign key column and the referenced column to be the same collation, so casting should not be necessary for joins.

Answer (score 0):

You could cast the pk and fk to varbinary(varchar length) whenever you compare the fields.

Something like:

```
Where CAST(yourPK As VarBinary(20)) = CAST(yourFK As VarBinary(20))
```